# Geodataframe: How to show a geometry based on a geodataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, geometry

I'm trying to plot "geometry" using pandas and geodatframe but i didn't have a result and i dont't see what's wrong with my code :

example on input:

example of the first line

MULTIPOLYGON (((639613.50999999978 1796921.8000000007, 639629.15000000037 1796915.6999999993, 639663.95999999996 1796904.5299999993, 639710.55999999959 1796904.5999999996, 639734.25 1796894.9100000001, 639796.00999999978 1796880.4800000004, 639802.38999999966 1796886.8200000003, 639798.79000000004 1796914.5700000003, 639802.37000000011 1796922.6699999999, 639802.34999999963 1796926.2100000009, 639788.36000000034 1796923.5800000001, 639779.26999999955 1796924.9600000009, 639765.58000000007 1796925.4299999997, 639744.73000000045 1796926.9499999993, 639687.12999999989 1796924.8100000005, 639651.75 1796926.25, 639623.51999999955 1796927.7300000004, 639611.20000000019 1796932.3000000007, 639607.5700000003 1796930.9399999995, 639613.50999999978 1796921.8000000007)))

**Code**:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

geodf = gpd.read_file('./my_file.csv')
geodf_new['geometry'] = geodf_new['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
geodf_new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geodf_new, crs='EPSG:4326')
```

**geodf_new.head()**:

[image]

**geodf_new.plot()**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample input data?

Comment: my input is a csv file, i updated my post with an example of data